# Atmel Flexible In-system Programmer and Atmel Studio 6. What are equivalents of those for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I have a course in school of Embedded Systems Programming where we are instructed to use Atmel Flexible In-system Programmer for coding tool and Atmel Studio 6 for developing and debugging. Because neither of these softwares run on Mac OS X, I was wondering what software could I use instead of what we were proposed.

Comment: So I am looking at the same problem. One option I have found is to use avarice (a tool installed with the avr toolchain). However, the problem with this is that it only works with JTAG programmers not ISP.